# Apostrophe is not showing as an apostrophe

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I have the following code to create some labels:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont{Sketch Nothing}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.pathmorphing,patterns}

\newcommand\myLabel[1]{
    \begin{tikzpicture}[decorate]
        % Outside of the label
        \node[text width=8cm, text height=4cm](myLabel) {};
        \draw[line width=1pt,line cap=rect,lightgray] (myLabel.north west) -| (myLabel.south east) -| (myLabel.north west) -- cycle;

        % Text
        \node[font=\fontsize{34}{25}\selectfont,align=center,darkgray]{\content};
        \node[anchor=east,font=\fontsize{12}{16}\selectfont,align=center,darkgray] at ([xshift=-0.5cm,yshift=-3.5cm]myLabel.north east) {\year};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
    \pagenumbering{gobble}
    \def \year{2017}
    \def \content{Confiture de\\ sureau}

    \myLabel{Confiture de\\ sureau} \myLabel{s}

    \def \content{Confiture\\ d'abricot}
    \vspace*{4mm}
    \myLabel{s} \myLabel{s}
\end{document}
```

It works fine except that the apostrophe from `d'abricot` is not showing as an apostrophe but as a $ sign.

The font library is available [here](http://www.dafont.com/fr/sketch-nothing.font). In the preview, one can see that the apostrophe is available in the font library.

To check if my font library was able to generate an apostrophe, I've used imagemagick to generate an image containing a text with apostrophe. It works perfectly.

<strike>I am suspecting that the problem comes from the use of tikz but I don't know how to solve it.</strike>

[Torbjørn T.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/586/torbj%c3%b8rn-t) mentioned that it's not related to tikz. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: It's fairly easy to confirm that TikZ is *not* the culprit. Here is a more minimal example demonstrating that: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Sketch Nothing}
\begin{document}
'
\end{document}` I get a dollar sign in LibreOffice Writer as well, for that matter, but not in the font viewer in Kubuntu.

Comment: Ok, so I am looking it from the wrong angle :'(

Comment: Your MWE generates no apostrophe-related issues when using a font other than `Sketch Nothing`. I downloaded the font from the site you provided. When I tried to "install" the font via the FontBook app, I got a couple of warnings about the font file having two issues, with the usability of the name table and with the name table structure. I'm no opentype font expert, but it looks like the font file isn't fully stable and reliable. (Aside: Upon clicking on "install font" and then compiling your MWE under LuaLaTeX, I encounter the dreaded dollar-sign-instead-of-apostrophe-symbol problem.)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is due to an issue with a specific (non-TeX) font.